# Why does "sudo apt update" cause a series of 403 connection errors?

Tags: command-line, sudo, vmware

Why does `sudo apt update` cause a series of 403 connection errors?

I have a Ubuntu 22.04 virtual machine using VMware on a Windows 10 Enterprise computer. Part of setting things up requires I run the
`sudo apt update` command.

or

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
```

both commands cause the same error messages.  They consist of:

```
403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
```

Either I need to do something to establish a network connection, I assume, or I need to find a way to do what I need through downloads and file shares with the host computer.  Either way, I need help.

Since I do not have the ability to share files or the clipboard memory with the Virtual Machine, I had to do a screenshot, but fortunately, I ran that through a pretty good OCR image to text converter so I can share this:

```
william@william-virtual-machine:~$ sudo apt update  
[sudo] password for william:  
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease 403 Forbidden (IP: 91.189.91.39 80] 
Err:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease 403 Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.39 80] 
Err:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.coR/ubuntu jammy.backports InRelease 403 Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.39 80) 
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease 403 Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.38 80] 
Reading package lists... Done  
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.  
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by
default.  
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease' is no longer signed.  
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jarmy/InRelease 403 Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]  
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.  
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by
default.  
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease' is no longer signed.  
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease 403
Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.39 80)  
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease
403 Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]  
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease' is no
longer signed.   
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.  
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.  
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jarny-securtty/InRelease 483
Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]  
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease' is no
longer signed.  
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.  
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details. 
william@william-virtual-machine
```

Here is a link to the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: you are right.  It is 22.04

Comment: You are right.  It is 22.04.  My mistake.  Also, I can not cut and save text from the vitrual machine to the host machine.  So I have to resort to doing this scrfeen capture.  If you click on the picture, it expands.  I guess I can do a image to text crm.

Comment: I am fixing this and I will update the OP.  I ran the image file through an decent online OCR program to convert it to text.

Comment: Text in a terminal is not an image. You can copy and paste it as text. Regarding your problem you seem to be behind some proxy.

Comment: There are obvious typos/errors in your paste; are those really there?  as *jammy* and *jamay* are different words thus errors are to be expected.. Question also asked at https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2474647